# Android try catch exception values for one method

Tags: java, android

There are a lot of exceptions when I do a try catch on Android.

ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

IOException, etc.

The question is, how do I know which Exception to use when applying these Exceptions to the source?

I wonder if there is an Exception that can be processed at once.

Comment: Catching all exceptions is bad practice, exception indicates you have done something illogically wrong and it is better to solve it than catching it in most cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer this question, **The question is, how do I know which Exception to use when applying these Exceptions to the source?**
 There is a very simple rule, when you call any method you must know what kindof exception does this method throw. You can check this via documentation of that particular language. For example if you are using java then consider Oracle documentation. For example if your parsing number that means number is in String form like

```
"123"
```

If you parse this number like.

```
Integer.parseInt("123")
```

This will be ok but if you parse like below

```
    Integer.parseInt("abc")
```

Definitelt this is not a valida number. In this case it will throw NUmberFOrmatException.
The question is how does one know what exception does it throw versy simple go for method documentation. If you exactly know what kind of exception will be thrown then use that exception class else you can Use super class of all exceptions that **Exception**.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks! I understand perfectly. :)

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html

**Look at the document img.**

[Documents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyZpy.png)

Here you can see the hierarchy of the classes/interfaces.

Look at the documentation for each Exception and use the class/interfaces that are common among them.

Of course you should be careful. Be careful, especially Throwable. If you catch things like StackOverflowError or OutOfMemoryError incorrectly, the program will be zombie.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Exception` which is superclass of all exceptions to catch all of it. But it's not recommended practice. You should catch known exceptions. Also IDE like intellij alerts you to catch exceptions if you forgot to do it.

Comment: Thanks for your effort :)

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 general cases for exceptions in Java:

1. Exceptions that you **must** catch (**Checked exceptions**)
2. Exceptions that you can catch (but do not do it until you have a really good reason) (**Unchecked exceptions**)

Actually there is one more case, the Exceptions that you don't want to catch in any circumstances (**Errors**), but let's leave it for now.

In the first case the code will not compile, and you'll see a message kind of (let's say in case of `IOException`):

```
Error:(15, 12) java: unreported exception java.io.IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

That means you're obligated to handle the Exception or delegate it to the next caller (rethrow it). This kind of exceptions considered to be *recoverable*, and require from you some action. You definitely will not miss it.

The second case do not requires any actions from you, and documentation of the method could not describe this exceptions at all. This exceptions are considered *unrecoverable* and simply intended to break the operation's chain because something went wrong (in case of `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` that you're accessing the index that do not exist for the particular array).

You can catch the high-level exceptions to cover more cases, but try to handle the narrowest exception.

Summary:

You don't need to know in advance all exceptions thrown by a method. If you're obligated to handle an exception, compiler will let you know.